# VisualStudio highlights all my code green, I don't know how to disable this effect/feature

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I was writing the code normally and then I fear I have accidentally pressed some shortcut that made my code all highlighted green, I tried to press some combos but nothing changed, I deleted the script from Unity and pasted the code into a new script, and it gave me the same issue. If I press anywhere it doesn't change anything and it only disappears for a moment when I edit the code and then it goes back to being green. I imagine this feature has a purpose that I'm not understanding but at the moment it's not doing anything for me except making the code less readable. Does anyone know what caused this effect, how can I remove it, and what is it's purpose? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two different IDEs. Which are you using?

Comment: Do you have any compiler warnings? Try and fix them first.

Comment: The code turns green usually when you comment it. If you have "//" or /* at some point you commented everything and that's why it is green. You just have to delete // or /*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "highlights green"? A green background, green text on regular background, green wavy line underneath the text, something else? Does it also happen on a new class file, that you didn't add code to yet?

Comment: Possibly VS is interpreting the code as a Definition. Try Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > and then change the background of Highlighted Definition to red and see if the code is now red instead of green.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the theme here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you **turned on** "Toggle Code Coverage Highlithing" under Tools menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it looks something like this then you've probably added the files to your project without adding them to git. The green indicates added but unstaged changes. Do you see plus signs in the ruler?

[image: VS Code screenshot showing one form of highlighting]